# Computing conditional probability with proxy variable

Tags: probability

Suppose $P(X | Y)$.

If I only know $P(X | Z)$ and $P(Z | Y)$, can I do 
$$       
       P(X|Y) = P(X|Z)P(Z|Y)? 
$$

Comment: Not unless $Z$ partitions the event space. However, $$P(X\mid Y) = P(X\mid Z)\cdot P(Z \mid Y) + P(X\mid \overline Z)\cdot P(\overline Z \mid Y).$$

Comment: @CarlHeckman That is: $\mathsf P(X\mid Y) = \mathsf P(X\mid Z, Y)\cdot\mathsf P(Z\mid Y)+\mathsf P(X\mid \overline Z, Y)\cdot \mathsf P(\overline Z\mid Y)$

Comment: PS: Unless $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

We toss a fair coin independently three times. Let $X$ be the event head on the first toss, $Y$ the event head on the second, and $Z$ the event head on the third.

Then $\Pr(X\mid Y)=1/2$ and $\Pr(X\mid Z)\Pr(Z\mid Y)=(1/2)(1/2)$.